# Shadow is not Visible While Using With ECSlidingController

Tags: ios

I'm using `ECSlidingController` in my iOS application. I've already checked requirements and demo. ECSlidingController working as how I wanted, but still couldnt add any shadow for view.

Here what I did, this is base view controller (`DetailViewController` is an UIViewController), which will be trigger sliding view and its name `DetailContextViewController` (left or right does not matter at all):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailContextViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underRightViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailAbout"];
    }
}
```

And here is DetailContextViewController (this is an UIViewController too):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.peekLeftAmount = 40.0f;
    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorLeftPeekAmount:self.peekLeftAmount];
    self.slidingViewController.underRightWidthLayout = ECVariableRevealWidth;
}
```

I've already added `QuartCore.h` and checked TabBar's attributes, i.e clip subviews is `false`. I've also tried shadow with `TableView`, so changed self.view.layer with self.tableView.layer and couldnt set the shadow again.

Is there anything wrong?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you set `topViewController`, but you need to set shadow parameters to your `topViewController`. For example:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
newTopViewController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
newTopViewController.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
newTopViewController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Is it just me or does this introduce a shocking amount of visual lag/hiccup? I ended up rendering a shadow asset and putting it in an imageview to the left of my topViewController. Seems to be a pervasive issue with using layers for shadows on iOS 6/7 UIKit.

Comment: @Dinkman123 I've been tearing my hair out dealing with the same thing.  From the author, "1.x sets the shadowPath for you and 2.x doesn't".

https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/issues/224

Comment: @MarkPhillip I generally avoid using layer shadows, I've seen performance issues here and many other situations using the built-in layer shadow functionality. It's pretty easy to render your own shadows as semi-transparent assets and the performance is vastly better all around.

Answer (score 2):

```
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

This would be better.Sometimes, newTopViewController is a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that topViewController is a UINavigationController.  I had this same problem and fixed it by adding the shadow to the UINavigationController view rather than the UIViewController view.  For example, instead of:

```
self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

do this instead:

```
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
self.navigationController.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

This is really simple compared to creating your own shadow layer and I haven't seen any performance problems.